# jQuery - use collection manipulation function on exsisting collection

Tags: jquery, arrays

Can I edit the data in a collection using a method, without having to reassign the new values to the old variable?

e.g.

```
var anArray = [1,2,3,4];

$.map(anArray, function(i){ return i * 2; });
```

There is now a new version of **anArray** floating about in memory.

How do I execute $.map() in a way that will simply change the data in the already existing array, without having to re-assign the variable:

```
var anArray = $.map(anArray, func...
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you shouldn't use `$.map`, as its very purpose is creating a *new* array.

If you need to modify the existing array, you can assign a value for each processed element within `$.each` callback:

```
$.each(anArray, function(index, value) {
  anArray[index] = doSomethingWith(value);
});
```